# Checking for page validity via If-Modified-Since or last-modified or something else

Tags: java, http, web, http-headers

I am writing some sort of my own search bot and come to an issue - how to check that page on the website was refreshed? I found that there is `last-modified` header that represents `The last modified date for the requested object`.

What I found that there is no way to ask for last-modified header, i.e. it is either installed  or not. I tried `If-Modified-Since` header and opposite  `If-Unmodified-Since`:

```
`header("If-Modified-Since", "Wed, 26 Mar 2014 06:50:01 GMT")`
```

, but most of the sites, I am interested in, return page and no last-modified error, or 304 error. So there is no way to check was their content modified since my bot's last visit.

Do I miss something? Is there some way to check for page modification?